# screenshot storage API

Tags: c#, storage

Я пишу автотесты на C# + Selenium и для failed тестов я делаю скриншоты. И вот появилась у меня необходимость хранить эти скриншоты не локально а заливать куда нибудь (например prnt.sc), получать ссылку на скрин и далее уже писать этот url в exception message, чтобы потом посмотреть с любого компа.
Предполагаю это будет post request с данными в формате json.
Подскажите какие-нибудь сервисы куда я могу таким образом постить скрины?

Вот как мне приходится пока обходиться:

```
public void TakeScreenshot(string fileName)
{
    string screenshot_folder = GetDirectory() + "\\screenshot\\";
    string location = screenshot_folder + fileName + ".png";            
    Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshot_folder);
    var ssdriver = Driver as ITakesScreenshot;
    var screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(location, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
    // Upload screenshot to prnt.sc
    Driver = new ChromeDriver(GetDirectory());
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://prnt.sc/");
    Driver.FindElementWithWait(By.Id("fileupload")).Click();
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    SendKeys.SendWait(location);
    SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    string ss_url = Driver.FindElementWithWait(By.Id("link-textbox")).Text;
    Console.WriteLine(ss_url);
    Driver.Close();
    Driver.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: может быть dropbox?

Comment: мне на самом деле без разницы ЧЕМ пользоваться, главное КАК это реализовать в коде

Comment: http://codehelper.ru/questions/35/new/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-image-hosting-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-api

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что я так долго искал )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий вариант который у меня получился:

```
public string UploadScreenshot(string fileName)
{
    var ssdriver = Driver as ITakesScreenshot;
    var screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();            
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(screenshot.AsByteArray);            
    HttpContent api_key = new StringContent("здесь будет ваш api key полученный при регистрации на imageshack.com");            
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        formData.Add(bytesContent, fileName, fileName);
        formData.Add(api_key, "api_key");
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://api.imageshack.com/v2/images", formData).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(result);
        JsonObject responseJson = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(responseStream);

        return "http://" + responseJson["result"]["images"][0]["direct_link"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
    }
}
```